# Can use font on my tex editor, but not on sharelatex, why?

Tags: fonts, packages, sharelatex

So I can write using Georgian font on my computer's TeX programme (I think MikTex?).  For this I needed to write the command "\usepackage [georgian]{babel}" and allow my computer to download something.  If I use the sharelatex programme, it says it can't compile "because no Georgian font encoding has been loaded so far.  A font encoding should be declared before babel".

How can I solve this?  (Am  I asking how can I make sharelatex use the package above?)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe compiling with `xelatex`?

Comment: how do i tell sharelatex to do this?  i've always just let it play and i can't seem to find now an option to change the compiler?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use sharelatex. Surely, an user will give  an answer.

Comment: sharelatex  has been overleaf for some years:-)  If you said what font you were using you may be able to upload it to overleaf or it may be a proprietary windows font so not available, it all depends. the warning about not having specified a font encoding is specific to your document, so please provide a small but complete document that works in your local miktex but not online.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get the error too, the language seems to look for a T8M encoding.

Comment: there is an option in the left sidebar menu to choose xelatex

Comment: found it - thanks.  so now it compiles with georgien text :D but at the cost of english text and numbers xD  with your example below, are you able to also have english text?  the error says something about "combining the english and the georgian" and says it may be fixed using global options?  (i can give the whole error if you want)

Comment: yes but "how to use babel" is a rather different question to the one you asked, the site works best with one question per post, however I set the main font to the Noto Serif Georgian (which is Ok for English actually) but only specified georgian to babel so that is setting up a single language document. If I used `[georgian.english]` as teh babel options english would stay the main language and you'd need to use babel commands to switch languages when needed

Comment: yes, but i don't have the problem on my miktex, only on sharelatex, so i'm not sure if i'm asking how to use babel.  anyway the situation is now: if i compile it using xelatex and using your commands below, i get georgian text, but number and english/latin letters don't appear

Comment: The packages you would need to install from CTAN to usethe PDFTeX support on your own box are [`babel-georgian`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-georgian) and [`georgian`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/georgian). However, I don’t think ShareLaTeX allows you to update the font map files you would need to.

Answer (score 1):

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Georgian}
\usepackage [georgian]{babel}

\begin{document}

გამარჯობა

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

from xelatex despite a spurious warning about TU encoding.

You should be able to use the Noto fonts on Overleaf

[image]

Comment: With this command numbers, latin letters, and punctuation don't appear.  (They appear as hollow white squares)

Comment: if i change the font in your command to "DejaVu Serif" I get what i want. thanks!

Comment: In order to use Noto Serif Georgian only for Georgian, you would use a command like `\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}` followed by `\babelfont[georgian]{rm}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Serif Georgian}`.